# CanvasJS in function only shows one chart (php, js)

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, canvasjs

```
function timeDataToPointChart($dataPoints,$title,$xlabel,$ylabel,$chartID) { 
?>
    
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
    
    
    var NameOfChart = "<?php echo $chartID; ?>"
     
    window[NameOfChart] = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title:{
        text: "<?php echo $title; ?>"
    },
    axisX:{
        title: "<?php echo $xlabel; ?>",
        valueFormatString: "MM/YYYY",
        crosshair: {
        enabled: true
        }
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "<?php echo $ylabel; ?>"
    },
    data: [
    {        
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        dataPoints:     
        
        <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    }
    ]
    });

      window[NameOfChart].render();
    
    function toggleDataSeries(e){
    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else{
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
      window[NameOfChart].render();
    }
    
    }
    </script>
    

    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 650px;"></div>
          
<?php
}
?>
```

I use this PHP function to generate my canvas chart. This works well, but if I call the function twice on a page, only one chart is shown.

Console shows the following error, but I don't understand what's wrong.

> CanvasJS namespace already exists. If you are loading both chart and
> stockchart scripts, just load stockchart alone as it includes all
> chart features.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't use `window.onload`. Make PHP generate _the entire file_ (e.g `myscript.php`), making sure it sets the content-type header to the JS mimetype, and then load _that_ as script using `<script src="myscript.php" type="text/javascript" async defer>`, where the important part is that `defer` keyword: deferred scripts only run once the browser's ready. Don't make PHP generate inline JS unless you want exactly this kind of situation where you can't even tell if a problem is due to server-side or client-side behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As described from canvasJs, i've implemented the code accordingly in my Laravel App like below

```
@foreach($records as $record)
<div id="chartContainer{{$record->employeeRequisitionId}}" style="height: 270px; width: 100%;"></div>
@endforeach

@push('after_scripts')

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        @foreach($records as $record)
        const chart{{$record->employeeRequisitionId}} = new CanvasJS.Chart ( "chartContainer{{$record->employeeRequisitionId}}", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2",
            title: {
                text: "Requisition According Fiscal Year"
            },
            axisY: {
                suffix: "%",
                scaleBreaks: {
                    autoCalculate: false
                }
            },
            data: [{
                type: "column",
                yValueFormatString: "#,##0\"%\"",
                indexLabel: "{y}",
                indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
                indexLabelFontColor: "white",
                dataPoints: {!! formatRequisitionAccordingFiscalYearData($record) !!}
            }]
        } );
        @endforeach

        @foreach($records as $record)
            chart{{$record->employeeRequisitionId}}.render ();
        @endforeach
    }
</script>
```

@endpush